# Finding min-max vertex-disjoint paths with a common source on planar graphs

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms

Given a planar unweighted graph, and a collection of vertex pairs $(s,t_1),\dots,(s,t_k)$ ($k\ge2$ is a constant), find $k$ vertex-disjoint (except source) paths from $s$ to $t_i$ such that the length of the longest path is minimized.

**Question:** Is there a polynomial-time algorithm for the problem?

Some related results:

- if $k$ is not fixed the problem is [NP-hard](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0166-218X%2801%2900294-3) even if $t_1=\dots=t_k$;
- if the input graph is weighted and sources of paths do not coincide, i.e. paths are $(s_1,t_1),\dots,(s_k,t_k)$ the problem is [NP-hard](http://www.sommer.jp/disjointsp.pdf) even for $k=2$;
- a problem with different objective, namely minimizing the sum of path lengths, is

  - solvable with the minimum cost flow algorithm for coinciding sources;
  - [NP-hard](http://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/pubs/publication.pl?ID=1588) for non-coinciding sources and general $k$;
  - open for non-coinciding sources and constant $k$.

Comment: It seems that there are many related results.  Can you summarize important related results in the question?

Comment: Is the input graph G weighted (that is, each edge has a positive-integer length)?  I had been assuming that G is not weighted, but I have realized that you are probably mixing up the two settings: (1) If G is weighted, then case of k=2 is NP-complete essentially by Theorem 14 in the paper by Kobayashi and Sommer which you linked to, which is also essentially the same as the last paragraph in Section 2 of [HP02] cited in my answer.  (2) If G is not weighted, then I cannot see why the paper by Kobayashi and Sommer implies the NP-hardness in case of k=2 and different sources.

Comment: In my settings, a graph is not weighted, so you are right: my claim on NP-hardness in case of K=2 and different sources is (probably) wrong.

Comment: I've updated the problem statement taking into account Tsuyoshi Ito's comment.

Answer (score 6):

This is not exactly what you asked, but the problem is NP-complete if *k* is not a constant but part of the input.

This follows from the proof of Theorem 1 in van der Holst and de Pina [HP02], which says: given a planar graph *G*, distinct vertices *s* and *t* in *G*, and positive integers *k* and *b*, it is NP-complete to decide whether there are *k* pairwise internally vertex-disjoint paths between *s* and *t* each of length at most *b*.

Note that the problem in the statement of Theorem 1 is different from yours in two respects.  One difference is, as I mentioned, that *k* is given as part of the input.  The other is that the problem in [HP02] is about paths with common endpoints instead of paths with a common source and different sinks.  I do not know how to fix the first difference; the difference is so large that it is likely that we will need a completely different proof to fix *k*.  But I know at least how to fix the second difference.

The proof of Theorem 1 in [HP02] gives a reduction from 3SAT.  This reduction has the following property: in the instance (*G*, *s*, *t*, *k*, *b*) constructed by the reduction, the degree of vertex *t* is always equal to *k*.  Let *t*<sub>1</sub>, …, *t*<sub>*k*</sub> be the *k* neighbors of *t*.  Then instead of asking whether there are *k* pairwise internally vertex-disjoint paths between *s* and *t* each of length at most *b*, we can equally ask whether there are pairwise vertex-disjoint-except-source paths *P*<sub>1</sub>, …, *P*<sub>*k*</sub> such that each *P*<sub>*i*</sub> is a path between *s* and *t*<sub>*i*</sub> of length at most *b*−1.

[HP02] H. van der Holst and J. C. de Pina.  Length-bounded disjoint paths in planar graphs.  *Discrete Applied Mathematics*, 120(1–3):251–261, Aug. 2002.  http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0166-218X%2801%2900294-3

Comment: I don't see a big difference between your settings (when $k$ is given in the input) and my original settings (when $k$ vertex pairs are given). The problem with a common source and different sinks looks "harder" than the problem with the same source and sink.

Comment: @SergeyPupyrev: You wrote that k is a constant.  (You wrote it because you knew what it means, didn’t you?)  From what I learned from a cursory look at relevant papers, whether k is a constant or not in related problems seems to make a huge difference in the current status of the complexity of the problem.

Comment: Let me clarify: your answer shows that if $k$ is not fixed then my original problem is NP-hard; otherwise, if $k$ is a constant then its complexity is unknown, right?

Comment: @SergeyPupyrev: I cannot find a paper which states the complexity in the case where k is a constant, but this only means that it is unknown _to me_.